# Can you do an :order in ruby after a find?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is it possible in ruby/rails to order a result set after doing a find?  For example, is it possible to do something like this

**Warning: Does not work**

```
if type == 1
  @items = mycompany.items
else
  @items = myhome.items
end

@items = @items :order => "created_at"
```

I would assume something like this should be possible, but I'm still very new to RoR and can't seem to find anything on google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why everyone's all "No you can't" when it's possible in named scopes.

For example, define as part of ActiveRecord::Base:

```
named_scope :by_created_at, :order_by => 'created_at'
```

This allows you to convert a simple relationship to an ordered one before it is actually retrieved:

```
@items = @items.by_created_at
```

As a note it's not a good idea to include scopes which have overlapping :order definitions as this causes them to be appended instead of over-riding each in turn.

However, in your example it's not too much of a stretch to imagine refactoring it as the following:

```
reference =
  case (type)
  when 1
     mycompany
  else
    myhome
  end

@items = reference.items.all(:order_by => 'created_at')
```

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to do one of these:

Sort when accessed:

```
if type == 1
  @items = mycompany.items(:order => 'created_at')
else
  @items = myhome.items(:order => 'created_at')
end
```

Sort after accessing:

```
@items.sort{|a,b| a.created_at <=> b.created_at}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also use the [`Symbol` to `Proc` shorthand](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/3/7/symbol-to-proc-shorthand) available in rails, along with [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003151) to simplify your sort statement, if you want to sort after collecting ActiveRecord objects:

```
@items.sort_by(&:created_at)
# is the same as @items.sort{ |a, b| a.created_at <=> b.created_at }
```